# Mail Server pam_authenticate failed

Tags: authentication, postfix, ubuntu-16.04, pam, sasl

In both cases smtp and smtps, When i try to send email using mail-client or login to smtp remotely i get in mail.log:

```
SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

And when i use the sasltest command:

```
# testsaslauthd -u mymail@mydomain.com -p 123456 -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

I get the following error on the `systemctl status saslauthd.service`

```
Oct 02 13:48:10 mydomain.com saslauthd[17624]: pam_unix(imap:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 02 13:48:10 mydomain.com saslauthd[17624]: pam_unix(imap:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
Oct 02 13:48:12 mydomain.com saslauthd[17624]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Oct 02 13:48:12 mydomain.com saslauthd[17624]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=mymail@mydomain.com] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
Oct 02 13:48:19 mydomain.com saslauthd[17628]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mysql.so): /lib/security/pam_mysql.so: undefined symbol: make_scrambled_password
Oct 02 13:48:19 mydomain.com saslauthd[17628]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_mysql.so
Oct 02 13:48:19 mydomain.com saslauthd[17628]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Module is unknown
Oct 02 13:48:19 mydomain.com saslauthd[17628]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=mymail@mydomain.com] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

I don't get what is wrong, it was working a while ago, my mail server is using (postfix 3.1 + dovecot 2.2.22 + mysql 5.7.19 + roundcube 1.2.4)

Any support please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the wrong version of policykit-1 being installed. I was on a 64bit machine and due to some miss-configuration, the i386 version was installed.

See if that is the case and if so, just do `sudo apt install policykit-1`

Good luck.